# setting dandelion plugin environment for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am trying to setup [dandelion](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dandelion-ecl/) plugin's environment on Eclipse but it is asking for port number also. I checked if any port has been occupied by clisp process, but found none.[image: Dandelion environment setup]

Any idea about how I should proceed ?

Comment: I expect that it's expecting there to be a CLISP instance listening on some port.  Are there installation instructions for Dandelion that describe any of the process?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor there is one documentation in german(not understandable to me) and all I tried was using the same ports they depicted in it. But it doesn't work. Also since it is a plug-in jar, all it needs is keeping it in plug-in folder of Eclipse to get it working, hence no special installation instruction.